# VB.NET not define dimension of ByRef array when call procedure or function

Tags: arrays, vb.net, vba

I moved from VBA language programming to VB.NET in Visual Studio 2015.
In VBA I do not have to define number of dimensions when calling procedure or function:

```
Sub Example(ByRef Arr() As String)
```

now in VB.NET I must define using comma in brackets:

```
Sub Example(ByRef Arr(,) As String) ' two dimensional array
```

When I pass array ByRef I have different number of dimensions of those Array (I support/check number of dimension inside of procedure)

How can I not define number of dimension of array in VB.NET when call procedure / function ?

Thanks

Comment: You are just stating a fact.  Arrays are done *very* differently in .NET.  You could for example also have used Arr()().  Jagged arrays are in general the better choice, they are a lot faster.   The compiler needs to know, the code it generates is very different.  If you don't want to nail it down then you need to declare the argument As Object.  This kind of flexibility is not a great idea, best to unlearn this VBA practice.

Comment: How many dimensions are supported? 1,2,3.....1000000?

Comment: I think max 3 dimensions.